# mocha testing with later DOM element interaction

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

In my unit tests I am calling an API whose response is a webpage with buttons and textboxes. Is there a way to simulate click events or keyboard event with the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go for Browser testing is using a headless browser, like PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html

There are instructions available for setting up tests with various test frameworks.

Headless Browsers are similar to "real" Browsers but meant for programmatically controlling them.

Comment: but the code will be send to CI and test. I think phantom.js will open an actual browser?

Comment: No phantomjs does not start another "real" browser. CI with travis is explained here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-PhantomJS